# Have received an COMException with error :HRESULT E_FAIL form a code that register an event handler for Itunes

Tags: c#

I have incorporated the following code ( found in STACKOVERFLOW)
in my Itunes monitor program:

```
  iTunesApp app = new iTunesApp();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    app.OnPlayerPlayEvent += new _IiTunesEvents_OnPlayerPlayEventEventHandler(app_OnPlayerPlayEvent);   
}
```

I am using Windows 10, with latest version of Itunes, and Visual Studio.

Unfortunately I get an exception.
It happens with every eventhandler I am trying to register:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>   'ItunesMonitorDj.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ItunesMonitorDj.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'.
>   The program '[2916] ItunesMonitorDj.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Comment: Please add the error you're getting to the question - we can't see your screen

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

'ItunesMonitorDj.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ItunesMonitorDj.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
The program '[2916] ItunesMonitorDj.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).